# Apache Camel: Validate RESTful JSON input based on databse base content

Tags: apache-camel

## Summary

A RESTful POST request `POST /request/{requestName}`

```
POST /request/CreateProduct

{
    "Code": 4711,
    "Name": "My product"
}
```

is to be validated:

1. if the given ${header.requestName} has a corresponding row in the
   database and
2. if the provided parameters match the requestName
   according to another table in the database, specifially if all required params are present and have the correct data type

### Current route sample config

```java
restConfiguration().component("netty4-http").port(8080).bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json);

rest("request/{requestName}").post()
    .consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    .produces("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
    .to("direct:newRequest");

from("direct:newRequest").transform().simple("Received request: ${header.requestName}, Body: ${in.body}");
```

### DB tables (MariaDB) to validate against

#### Table: request

```
id | name
------------------
 1 | CreateProduct
 2 | UpdateProduct
 3 | DeleteProduct
```

#### Table: request_parameter

```
id | name | type
-------------------
 1 | Code  | INT
 2 | Name  | STRING
 2 | Price | INT
```

#### Table request_to_parameter

```
request | paramater | required
------------------------------
      1 |         1 |        1
      1 |         2 |        1
      1 |         3 |        0
```

### Question

Is this possible with pure Camel? Or should I implement my own helper function? How to I include my own custom function in a Camel route?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement a customer processor as described here:
http://camel.apache.org/processor.html

With the Exchange object you have access to header and body and can extract the necessary information to validate.